# How can I get this query to work? (Firestore)

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the document ID of the result of a query in my onUpdate function. This is what I have:

```
console.log(change.after.id)
const queryRef = await db.collection('groups').where('groupDetails', '==', [change.after.id]).get()
console.log(queryRef.id)
```

In my log, I'm getting undefined:
[image]

but when I look in firebase and filter the query it's the same as to what I have:
[image]
[image]

it's probably something simple but I can't find the answer and it's driving me crazy! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a query against a collection using [get()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#get), you are going to get back a [QuerySnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) that contains zero or more documents that match your query.  It's important to realize that even if you are expecting just one document, Firestore doesn't know that, and requires you to check the size of the result set inside the QuerySnapshot.  Right now, your code is just assuming there is one document, and that's not going to work.

Using the API of the QuerySnapshot, your code should look more like this:

```
const querySnapshot = await db
    .collection('groups')
    .where('groupDetails', '==', [change.after.id])
    .get()
if (querySnapshot.docs.length > 0) {
    console.log(querySnapshot.docs[0].id)
}
else {
    console.log("No documents")
}
```

This will print the ID of the first document in the result set, if there were results that matched the query.